# Rotation returns to starting point after animation is done

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

I'm doing a simple turn 90 degrees animation in Unity. When the animation ends, my animation-object snaps back to the rotation where it started. This is bad because the point of the animation is to do a left-turn and then continue from that rotation.

I didn't find a fitting solution for this anywhere else, so I'm glad for any help. If you have any other idea how i can do a "turn animation" with unity animations, I'm happy to here that too! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by going into your animator, select the transition (white-arrow) going away from the turn animation, and then move the "transition boundary" a bit.

[image]

It should then look something like this:
[image]

Hope this helped you!

Answer (score 0):

For me this tutorial helped me. It explains how to apply root motion with animation so the game object actually stays rotated after the turn animation finished.

1. Tick the "Apply Root Motion"-Checkbox in the Animator
   [Animator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcG5V.png)
2. On your Idle Character Prefab under the 'Rig'-Tab choose Animation Type Humanoid and hit Apply
   [Main Rig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Zd57.png)
3. Select all your other Animation Prefabs and under the 'Rig'-Tab choose also Humanoid as Animation Type but as the Avatar Definition choose the Avatar that was created in the last step.
   [Other Rigs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPDc0.png)
4. Put the Avatar into the Animator
   [Animator Final](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytYra.png)

I also *just discovered* this through this video, **so I may miss some details.** But these are the basics that helped my character keep its rotation through Animation :)

https://youtu.be/Xl_5roq4UlI?t=150